# Is it possible to create two dimensional array with Array()?

Tags: vba

Creation of one dimensional array is straightforward :

```
Dim A As Variant
A = Array(10,20,30)
```

Is it possible to create two dimensional array with Array() ? Is there any other method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I knew I'd seen this somewhere before, but had to search for a bit:

```
Sub test()
Dim A As Variant
A = [{1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}]
Debug.Print A(2, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice workaround. The `[..]` expects a worksheet range, but you provide an value array instead. Awesome!

Comment: Note that this technique creates a 1-based array, unlike the Array() function which returns a zero-based array. Also, it works in Excel but not in Access.

Comment: Tom, I agree and like your answer best.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of arrays using the Array() function syntax:

```
  x = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), Array(100, 101), Array(200, 201, 202))
  debug.print x(2)(1)
  201
```

This not actually a two-dimension array. This technique is used a lot in other languages.

Comment: Tom, this is the best answer. I tried to do this (it doesn't come up in day-to-day work for me, so haven't memorized it) but somehow botched the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. With `Array function` You can only specify a *list of values*, not dimemsions.

**Array Function Syntax**

> Array(arglist)

The required `arglist` argument is a comma-delimited **list of values** that are assigned to the elements of the array contained within the Variant.

And you can affect **lower bound**. Use **Option Base 1** then the `Array()` function  returns array whith lower bound **1**. Only if `Array()` function is qualified with type library name e.g. `VBA.Array()` then `Option Base` does not affect the lower bound of the array returned by `Array()` function.

To create 2D array simply specify dimensions e.g. like this

```
Dim multiA(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String
```

Or use `ReDim` like this

```
Dim multiA As Variant
ReDim multiA(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
```